# PowerPivot Vs SSRS capabilities

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence, powerpivot

I am just curious to know the capabilities of PowerPivot(SharePoint) when it comes head on with SSRS (SharePoint) . I have worked extensively on SSRS but I am new to PowerPivot .

PowerPivot clearly wins when it comes to filters and slicers as in SSRS we have to use VB code to populate unique SPList Column values into the filter drop down.However I am not able to see how PowerPivot can be used to implement drill down or subreport functionalities as in SSRS .

Is it possible to do so in PowerPivot ? Is PowerPivot just a data model which can be used along with Power View or Can PowerPivot be used for hardcore reporting requirements as in SSRS ?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

To tackle the question "*I am not able to see how PowerPivot can be used to implement drill down or subreport functionalities as in SSRS*".  It is possible to create a drilldown in PowerView, to do this you need to create a hierarchy.  This [webpage](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Hierarchies-in-Power-View-328fc89d-693e-4fa3-a0b8-03ce1f4eb7f0) will give you some details on how to do that.  Subreports as implemented in SSRS, so far l have not been able to re-create that in Power View.

I would also suggest looking at the new dashboard capabilities that have just been released see - [powerbi-dashboards](http://www.powerbi.com/dashboards).  I've been playing with it for a few days, some really nice new features.  IMHO still not a replacement for SSRS.  My personal opinion at this moment in time, Power View cannot do all that SSRS is capable of.  It might be a replacement for SSRS in the future, when will that happen ? At the moment l cannot find any roadmap indicating the future for PowerBI or SSRS, much to my frustration.

Comment: Update - drill down functionality has been implemented in PowerBI  see https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/467072-drill-down-in-a-visualization-in-power-bi

Answer (score 0):

As BobF mentioned, you can create drilldown views in PowerPivot via the use of hierarchies. One note on this is that hierarchies are only available in PowerPivot 2013 (not 2010): https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Whats-new-in-Power-Pivot-in-Microsoft-Excel-2013-930be6c5-e839-4860-8c74-8a5e2cba1279?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

I am also a big fan of PowerView & the PowerBI dashboard capabilities offered by PowerPivot - these have helped my team gain a lot of traction in our organization and with our clients.

While I don't have much first-hand experience with SSRS, here's some feedback from our team (who is well-versed in both):

- PowerPivot is fast & flexible
- PowerPivot allows you to easily develop tools that enable users to self-service on most requests
- PowerPivot puts some dependencies on the user (e.g. access to SharePoint or appropriate version of Excel)
- PowerPivot is not necessarily as robust as SSRS, but can be less work
- As BobF mentioned, Microsoft hasn't been great about communicating the roadmap or future of PowerBI, so it's tough to know where it's going
- The Dev process can be a bit painful for PowerPivot if you aren't doing the development in a tabular server (e.g. trying to do the Dev in Excel itself)

Comment: Just to comment on requirements you will need an Office 365 subscription, to ensure you get all the latest updates.  As of this year the Office 2013 professional plus does not get the latest updates of Power View and most likely any other updates to Power BI l suspect.  Microsoft seem to be completely focused on the cloud.  Even if you have on premise share-point, you might not be able to get all the features of Power BI that is offered on-line.  Will those trickle down to on-prem ?  Best l saw was a "maybe"

Comment: @BobF raises a great point - at this point in time, the desktop solutions do not offer the full feature set as the SharePoint offerings. For example, you cannot export PowerView reports to PowerPoint from Excel - you must do it from SharePoint.